# How to display data grouping by date?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have some rows in Mysql data base with field datetime.
How I can display data on page grouping by date?

For example two rows have the same date: `2015-09-14` 
How I can show these like as:

```
09 September
row 1
row 2
```

Comment: You have to improve your sample data. Please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you should order by the `datetime` field and then in the application logic I'd go with:

```
foreach(rows as row){
  if(previous date != date of row){
    output date
  }
  output row 
  previous date = date of row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isnt clear for your answer

But maybe something like this

```
 SELECT datetime, count(*)
 FROM YourTable
 GROUP BY datetime
```

But if you want every row

```
 SELECT *
 FROM YourTable
 ORDER BY datetime
```

Comment: If I get all rows by one query, how after in PHP I can group data  by time/

Comment: This is a just a suggestion, you should update your question with a more detailed sample and desire output so I can give you a better solution.  Please read the link I provide in my comment